# How to get row and column name of a selected checkbox inside a table cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When I select a checkbox, it should give me the time (row) and day (column) value using javascript. If possible I should put these selected values into two separate arrays for time and day.

For example:

[image]

Comment: you use js to catch events and locate html elements based on things like checkbox clicks.  An image does not tell us how the page is rendered. Also you are more likely to get help if you've shown what you have tried first. please read [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        let checkedCol = this.closest('tr').cells[0];
        let time = checkedCol.textContent;
        let colInd = parseInt($(this).parent().index());
        let day = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:first').find("td").eq(colInd).text();
        alert("Time : " + time + "  Day : " + day);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>Mon</td>
  <td>Tue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8-12</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="1"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>12-17</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="1"></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="1"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```